# Passing variables to custom templates

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7 I have a web site with dozens of custom templates. I used `theme()` to pass variables to my templates defined in `hook_theme()` in a page callback defined in hook_menu. How do you do this in Drupal 8? The `theme()` function is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal 8 uses [render arrays](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8) for the structure, and [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) to render them (as can Drupal 7 for themeing, incidentally).

The examples from the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195739) are as good as any:

Drupal 7

```
// Theme a table with header and row data.
$markup = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'my-module-table')));

// Render a pager.
$markup = theme('pager');
```

Drupal 8

```
// Theme is available as an element type (may have additional processing in rendering).
$table = array(
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'my-module-table',
  ),
);
$markup = drupal_render($table);

// Pager is not an element type, use #theme directly.
$pager = array('#theme' => 'pager');
$markup .= drupal_render($pager);
```

There's a useful warning too:

> Also note that when preparing output for Twig templates (in preprocess functions) it is preferable to avoid calling drupal_render() whenever possible. The Twig environment in Drupal 8 will automatically render any render arrays printed in the template, allowing for manipulation by later preprocess functions and preventing unnecessary rendering if the variable is never printed in the template.

Comment: I think in the example `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` should be used instead of `drupal_render()` which is deprecated.